# How to toggle a pin in Harmony framework for a pic?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, mplab, mplab-harmony

I'm new to pic's and the harmony framework, and i'm trying to toggle a pin from high to low and vice versa in the interrupt callback of the Timer.

I configured my oscillator to operate at 32 MHz

[image]

[image]

or at least is what appears here, so i suppose it's right:
[image]

Then i configured a Timer Driver, with prescale 256, so each tick is 8us:

[image]

Now my question, i want an interrupt to happen at each 8us, and i want to toggle a pin (RG0) at each interrupt. How can that be done?

[image]

I see what seems the interrupt code at the file `system_interrupt.c`:
[image]

But if inside that function i put the following line:

`LATGINV = 0x00000001;` nothing happens, i go check on the oscilloscope the signal and there is no toggle.

If i put the same line on `main.c` it works, the problems is that it doesn't seem to be accessible in `system_interrupt.c`

Comment: You have to write code in callback function. It is not generated by Harmony as it is your application code.

Comment: Hi @Swanand you mean the ```IntHandlerDrvTmrInstance0``` function right?

Comment: Yes! IntHandlerDrvTmrInstance0

Comment: @Swanand but is it a good solution to put code inside that function? It is code generated, every time i generate code i need to check what i need to keep inside, but maybe it's the only way.

Comment: Why you want to generate code multiple times? You configure the Harmony, Generate basic code and then start writing your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of configuring timers in harmony v2.

i.e. `Static` or `Dynamic`

For static timers you need to add your handling code into the `system-interrupt.c` file timer handler. See [here](https://microchipdeveloper.com/harmony:tmr-static)

For dynamic timers you can specify a custom handler in your application code. See [here](https://microchipdeveloper.com/harmony:tmr-dynamic). See 'Creating the ISR' and 'Registering the ISR' sections.

I would use the harmony `timer system service`, see [here](https://microchipdeveloper.com/harmony:tmr-sys), which is a bit simpler implementation and similar to dynamic implementation but might result in less accurate timing due to extra software handling.

`LATGINV` is not typical usage.

There is pin toggle example code in this example.

To toggle your LATG 0 pin with harmony you may do the following

**Initialization**

```
PLIB_PORTS_PinDirectionOutputSet(PORTS_ID_0, PORT_CHANNEL_G, PORTS_BIT_POS_0);
```

**Toggling**

```
PLIB_PORTS_PinToggle(PORTS_ID_0, PORT_CHANNEL_G, PORTS_BIT_POS_0);
```

The [microchip developer help](https://microchipdeveloper.com/harmony:start) is quite in depth and I'd recommend reading

Comment: Hi @pm101 thanks for the tip. Still in ```system_interrupt.c``` it doesn't seem to work. the invert of the pin.

Comment: LATGINV will not set a pin. Did you see `PLIB_PORTS_PinDirectionOutputSet(PORTS_ID_0, PORT_CHANNEL_A, PORTS_BIT_POS_0);` and `PLIB_PORTS_PinToggle(PORTS_ID_0, PORT_CHANNEL_F, PORTS_BIT_POS_0);` in the timer system service example?

Comment: i already tried using that functions but i will check again, about the LATGINV = 0x00000001 it works when i run in main, it seems valid. Maybe the problem is more than that, the interrupt probably is never called i need to understand why. Thanks.

Comment: You had to learn to use the debugger, then check if the ISR is called!